# Why does simmer's get_attribute function require the environment as an argument?

Tags: r

The `get_attribute` function in simmer takes the simulation environment as an argument (`.env`). However, it has to be called while an arrival is running, so presumably it already knows which simulation environment it's being called in. Why is the argument necessary?

Compare to `set_attribute`, which does not require the environment as an argument.

My guesses for the differences:

1. `set_attribute` creates an activity in the environment's trajectory, whereas `get_attribute` is a function that can be called within an activity creation's niladic function calls. This allows the former knowledge of the environment, in a way that doesn't allow `get_attribute` the same information.
2. There are use cases where you can pull attributes out of a second simulation environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trajectories and simulation environments are independent C++ objects under the hood. `set_attribute` appends an activity to the trajectory's C++ chain, and the arrival that is traversing that activity at a given simulation time is able to call its parent simulator to modify an attribute at C++ level. `get_attribute` and other getters, however, are executed at R level, and thus they need a reference to the intended simulation environment, otherwise they have no way of knowing what's the enclosing C++ execution environment.